# ios view still there after loading new view

Tags: ios, memory, rootview

When I set a new rootViewController:

```
self.appDelegate.contactsView = [[Contacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Contacts" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.appDelegate.contactsView;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I can still do stuff with the view I just left.

For example when I leave my home view, that has a logout button top left, on the contacts view I can still click the logout button even though it's not visible.

This only happens on iPhone5.

Also, it doesn't appear memory is being reclaimed when I attach a new view.  When I go back and forth between my contacts and home screens memory usage only ever increases.

I had a couple of leaks but I got them fixed up.  Now I can't figure out why memory usage only ever rises.  I can "simulate memory warning" and it gets me back maybe .25MBs, but it's no where near as low as when I first load it and have only used one or two views.

I am using ARC.  My view controllers are defined in my appdelegate like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *contactsView;
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *homeView;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the view in question `strong`? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Using ARC, yes.  The view is not strong.